# canvas arc render discrepancy on firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, cross-browser

I am trying to draw a rectangle made up of small circles along the four sides of the rectangle. Here is my code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = 200;
var h = 100;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";

// top and bottom
for(var i = x, len = x+w ; i < len ; i = i+4) {
ctx.arc(i, y, 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.arc(i, y+h, 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
}

// right and left
for(var i = y, len = y+h ; i < len ; i = i+4) {
ctx.arc(x, i, 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.arc(x+w, i, 0.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
}   

ctx.fill();
```

Even though this code works as I would like it to be on Chrome, the render on Firefox 16.0.1 is wrong (or different). I noticed that the code works as I intend it to be on Firefox when I add beginPath and stroke before and after every arc method.

PS: the problem seems to occur with fill, not stroke. So I changed it in the example code. Here is the link to the example: http://jsfiddle.net/GACsh/

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks the same on both Firefox and Chrome here.

http://jsfiddle.net/X7GYg/

`"#000000CC"` is not a valid fillStyle, its not a valid hex RGB value. If you need alpha you need to use `"rgba(0,0,0,150)"` etc.

Comment: sorry. the difference seems to occur with fill, not stroke. Here is the link to an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GACsh/

Comment: That's very interesting! Firefox is following the specification correctly here, I'm not sure why Chrome isn't because it always has done the right thing in my tests with arcs. I imagine what you want to accomplish is this: http://jsfiddle.net/GACsh/1/

Comment: For the record Firefox, Opera and IE10 all show your code correctly. Later I'll file a bug with Chrome over this

Comment: Yeah, per order of the specification, when you write the first "arc" in a path there's an implicit move to. For every single "arc" after that one it automatically makes a line from the end of the last segment to the start of the new arc, and you want to avoid that, so you gotta put in the `moveTo`s. Hope your project goes well!